# Analytic solution to an integral equation

Tags: functional-analysis, integral-equations

I am trying to analytically solve a simple looking integral equation:
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1 e^{(1-t)x} \varphi(t) dt = 1, \hspace{0.2cm} \forall x \in [-1,0],
\end{align*}
but could neither say whether it is solvable and what function $\varphi(t)$ solves the equation.

In the case that this is not solvable, I would like to consider approximate solutions, i.e. roughly speaking
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^1 e^{(1-t)x} \varphi(t) dt \approx 1, \hspace{0.2cm} \forall x \in [-1,0],
\end{align*}
either in the sense of the $L^2$-norm or the uniform-norm. Whichever is easier!

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I don't believe there can be a solution for every $x$ in the given domain.  Note that $e^{(1-t)x}$ is monotone and dependent on $x$, while $\phi$ is not dependent on $x$.  If you differentiated both sides w.r.t. $x$, you'd end up with $$\int_0^1e^{(1-t)x}(1-t)\phi(t)~\mathrm dt=0$$Subtract this from the original and you get$$\int_0^1e^{(1-t)x}t\phi(t)~\mathrm dt=1$$Not sure if these help, but yeah...

Comment: For the second solution, you might want to clarify what you mean by $\approx1$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt: Thanks, I tried to be more specific now

Comment: Maybe a numerical approximation could help you guess analytic solutions or to show that none exist.

Comment: Your equation means $\int_{0}^1 e^{-tx} \varphi(t) dt = e^{-x}$, so the obvious "solution" would be the distribution $\phi(t)=\delta(t-1).$

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense because of the independent variable $x$, with which we can conclude that $\int_{0}^1 e^{(1-t)x} t^n  \varphi(t) dt = 1$ holds for all $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ .

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that there is an integrable function $\phi$ on $[0,1]$ such that
$$\forall\,x\in[-1,0],\qquad \int_0^1e^{-xt}\phi(t)dt=e^{-x}\tag{1}$$
Taking successive derivatives and evaluating the result for $x=0$ we see that
$$\forall, n\in\mathbb{N},\quad \int_0^1 t^n \phi(t)dt=1$$
This implies that for every polynomial $P(X)\in \mathbb{R}[X]$ we have
$$\int_0^1 P(t) \phi(t)dt=P(1)$$
In particular,
$$\forall\,Q(X)\in \mathbb{R}[X],\qquad \int_0^1 Q(t)(t-1) \phi(t)dt=0$$
By Weirstrass theorem every continuous function on $[0,1]$ is the uniform limit of a sequence of  polynomials. Thus, we conclude from the above result that
$$\forall\,f\in C([0,1]),\qquad \int_0^1f(t)(t-1)\phi(t) dt=0$$
But this means that $(t-1)\phi(t)=0~ a.e.$, and consequently
$\phi(t)=0~ a.e.$ which is absurd because it contradicts $(1)$.

As a conclusion: there is no solution $\phi$ to $(1)$ in the space of integrable functions on $[0,1]$.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in a comment (and as Felix Klein showed in more detail), a solution of the equation should behave like the distribution $\delta(t-1),$ so it's easy to find approximate solutions:
If $$\varphi(t)=\frac1\epsilon\chi_{[1-\epsilon,1]}(t),$$ the integral becomes $$\int_{0}^1 e^{(1-t)x} \varphi(t) dt = \frac{e^{\epsilon x}-1}{\epsilon x},$$
if $$\varphi(t)=\frac1\epsilon e^{(t-1)/\epsilon},$$ we have
$$\int_{0}^1 e^{(1-t)x} \varphi(t) dt = \frac{1-e^{x-1/\epsilon}}{1-\epsilon x}.$$ Both expressions converge to $1$ uniformly in every finite $x$-interval as $\epsilon\rightarrow0.$